# Как преобразовть таблицу в JSON?

Tags: python, json, парсер, pandas, обработка-данных

Есть такой DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['TEST', 'TEST2'], 'DATA': ['156;256','123']})
```

```
    ID  DATA
0   TEST    156;256
1   TEST2   123
```

Как лучше всего сделать из таблицы JSON вида:

```
[
    {
        "nubmers": {
            "index": [
                {
                    "type": "phone",
                    "value": "156"
                },
                {
                    "type": "phone",
                    "value": "256"
                }
            ]
        },
        "nameID": "TEST"
    },
    {
        "nubmers": {
            "index": [
                {
                    "type": "phone",
                    "value": "123"
                }
            ]
        },
        "nameID": "TEST2"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот основная часть решения:

```
res = (df
       .assign(DATA=df["DATA"].str.split(";"))
       .explode("DATA")
       .rename(columns={"ID":"nameID", "DATA":"value"})
       .assign(type="phone")
       .groupby("nameID")
       .apply(lambda x: x.drop(columns="nameID").to_dict("records"))
       .to_dict())
```

результат:

```
In [332]: res
Out[332]:
{'TEST': [{'value': '156', 'type': 'phone'},
  {'value': '256', 'type': 'phone'}],
 'TEST2': [{'value': '123', 'type': 'phone'}]}
```

Оставшуюся часть предлагаю вам для разнообразия сделать самому ;)

Comment: спасибо, можно еще вопрос? Вот вы сделали что выводит значения TEST и TEST2, а как сделать чтобы вместо было статическое слово?

Comment: @user433816, я думаю лучше задать новый вопрос с новым результатом, который вы хотите получить. Это решение основано на приведенном в вопросе JSON, который вы хотели получить